# Is there a default constructor in .NET as there is in C#?

Tags: .net, constructor, unity-game-engine, unityscript, jscript.net

I'm learning about constructors and am still a bit of a newbie in programming so apologies in advance if I'm using any terminology incorrectly. I believe that what I've read is there's a handy default constructor in C# that allows you to declare properties in object initialization like this…

```
Cat cat = new Cat { Age = 10, Name = "Fluffy" };
```

However I'm using UnityScript in the Unity3D engine and this language is, although often referred to as Javascript, more similar to JScript.NET. Is there a default constructor like the C# one available when initializing an object?

Currently what I have to do is initialize the object then set each property one at a time. Alternatively I can create a constructor I can use but I'm just curious if there's already a default one there like in C#?

Comment: `in .NET as there is in C#?` - WHAT?!?

Comment: C# != JavaScript.  One's object-oriented; the other's a prototype language.  Not the same.

Comment: In you example object initializer is used (it isn't constructor). I am not sure if you can use it on the UnityScript, but here is information about it in c# http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384062.aspx , maybe it will help.

Comment: @duffymo Unity calls UnityScript JavaScript. It's a Mono-based language built on Boo. Still, this question title is nonsensical.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are asking about is not called [the default constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645608%28v=vs.71%29.aspx). It's called an [object initializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384062.aspx).

It would not be a feature of .NET or Mono, because those are not languages; initializers are language features. I have tried to use them in UnityScript, but they either aren't implemented (I'm betting on that), or their syntax is just undocumented.

For your own classes/structs, I don't think they're frequently useful, but they are useful for working with classes/structs for which you don't control the source:

```
var v = new Vector3 { y = .5F }; // x and z are still zero, the default for floats
```

If you were able to write Vector3, you could give it a constructor like this:

```
public Vector3(x = 0, y = 0, z = 0) : this()
{
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.z = z;
}
```

and used [named parameter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264739.aspx) syntax, as such:

```
var v = new Vector3(y: .5F);
```

Given initializer syntax, there would be no point to bother with doing that, for a simple mutable struct like Vector3, but when you start working with [readonly](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/acdd6hb7.aspx) fields and privately set [properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x9fsa0sw.aspx), you'll find constructors to be more valuable.

Comment: I know another guy with a similar name ;)

Answer (score 5):

Unless `Cat` is a `struct`, it may not have a default constructor: it all depends on the class. If all constructors of a class take parameters (i.e. there is no default constructor) the construct

```
new MyClass { ... }
```

would be illegal.

Note that you can use the same initialization construct even for classes that lack default constructors: all you need is to call the non-default one, like this:

```
class Cat {
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public string Age {get;set;}
    public Cat(string name) {Name = name;}
}

Cat myCat = new Cat("Fluffy") {Age = 10 };
```

Comment: Maybe it's a bit over my head :)

Comment: UnityScript isn't very well documented right now.

I simply saw someone set properties on initializing an object in a single line and it looked rather neater than my usual way of setting each property one line at a time. I wondered if it was possible in UnityScript but it seems it may just be unique to C#.

Comment: @Essential Unityscript is a different language, with its own syntax that is different from C#. I am sure it would be possible for Unityscript designers to add support for this sort of syntax, but one cannot expect it to be available automatically.